# Error when changing selectedValue in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdown menus which are populated using tableAdapters, the list_model dropdown menu is fully dependent on the list_make dropdown menu as it determines which models to show depending on which make has been clicked on, here is the dropdown menus:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="list_make" class="form-control padding" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="makeODS" DataTextField="make"  DataValueField="ID" onselectedindexchanged="list_make_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("makeID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="makeODS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="getMakes"  TypeName="list_dataTableAdapters.MakesTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="list_model" class="form-control padding" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="modelODS" DataTextField="model" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("modelID") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="modelODS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetModelsByMakeID" TypeName="list_dataTableAdapters.ModelsTableAdapter">
               <SelectParameters>
                   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="list_make" Name="make_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
               </SelectParameters>
   </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Note that these dropdown lists are in my EditItemTemplate and when the edit button is clicked the SelectedValue is correctly retrieved however when I select  a new item in the list_make I get this error

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control**

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Also if it helps I have this code in the list_make_SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
 protected void list_make_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listView = listview_car.Items[0].FindControl("list_model") as DropDownList;
    listView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What is listview_car? It seems really weird to create a reference to an object and then trying to databind it, are you sure you're don't want to do listview_car.DataSource = myCarSource; and then databind your listview_car?

Comment: listview_car is a listview, it uses an SqlDataSource to databind. And yes I am sure, everything works perfect how it is, it's just when a user edits the dropdown menus that are populated with TableAdapters it gives that error @ThomasLindvall